# Setting inputs for CaseIteratorDriver in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

What is the best way to set inputs in CaseIteratorDriver?  An example shows direct assignment via: `self.driver.case_inputs.param_name = [0,1,2]`  That doesn't seem to properly get handled when running CaseIteratorDriver in parallel.  I tried setting them via `self.driver.setsinputs(CaseArray({'x':[0,1,2]})` but that fails too.  It appears CaseArray doesn't generate the 'generator' object that set_inputs is expecting.  What classes do generate the correct object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it to a list should have worked fine. What is the behavior you're seeing that makes you think it is not working in parallel?

How are you running it in parallel? By setting `sequential=False`?

Comment: Checked the openmdao.log file when `sequential=False` and it does look like it's launching the workflow in parallel when I set it with a list, but I don't get any evidence in the output.  `eval_responses()` just returns what I think is the last value.  How do I get a list of responses that corresponds to the input list?

Comment: Okay, never mind the class documentation.  The results of a set of runs appears to be stored in a variable tree `CaseIteratorDriver.case_outputs`   Now that I can find the output, I can see that it is running in parallel.